# ASM Analyze MethodNode failure

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation, jvm-bytecode

I am wondering whether I can create an MethodNode directly and then analyze it. Therefore, I write below code to test:

```
        ClassNode classNode = new ClassNode(Opcodes.ASM5);
        classNode.visit(V1_8, ACC_PUBLIC + ACC_SUPER, className, null, Type.getInternalName(BaseTemplate.class), null);

        constructClass(classNode, className);


        //THREAD SAFE but looks badly. 
        if(_node == null){
            synchronized(this){
                if(_node==null){
                    MethodType tmpType = MethodType.methodType(int.class);
                    _node = (MethodNode) classNode.visitMethod(ACC_PUBLIC, Constants.INVOKE_EXACT, tmpType.toMethodDescriptorString(),
                            null, new String[] { "java/lang/Throwable" });
                    _node.visitCode();
                    _node.visitInsn(ICONST_0);
                    _node.visitInsn(IRETURN);
                    //_node.visitMaxs(-1, -1);
                    _node.visitEnd();
                    Analyzer _analyzer = new Analyzer(new SourceInterpreter());
                    try {
                        _analyzer.analyze(className, _node);
                    } catch (AnalyzerException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Unfortunately, the exception is thrown when calling `_analyzer.analyze()`:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Trying to access an inexistant local variable 0
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.Frame.setLocal(Frame.java:175) ~[na:5.0.3]
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.Analyzer.analyze(Analyzer.java:165) ~[na:5.0.3]
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.compile(MethodHandle.java:1222) ~[na:na]
```

I believe it is caused by the unset of `maxStack` and `maxLocals`. It seems that I have to calculate correct `maxStack` and `maxLocals`, and then calling `visitMax()` here. Is there any other method without calculation both values?

Another way I used previously is some code like:

```
       ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES);
       cw.visit(V1_8, ACC_PUBLIC + ACC_SUPER, className, null, Type.getInternalName(BaseTemplate.class), null);
       constructClass(cw, className);


            //THREAD SAFE but looks badly.
            if(_node == null){
                    synchronized(this){
                            if(_node==null){
                                    _node = new MethodNode(ACC_PUBLIC, Constants.INVOKE_EXACT, type.toMethodDescriptorString(),
                                        null, new String[] { "java/lang/Throwable" });
                                    generateMethod(_node, className);
                            }
                    }
            }
            _node.accept(cw);
            cw.visitEnd();

             ClassNode classNode = new ClassNode(ASM5);
                    ClassReader reader = new ClassReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(cw.toByteArray()));
                    reader.accept(classNode, 0);

            //Then extract MethodNode from ClassNode and make analyzation.
```

This works, but I donot like it as it includes multiple visiting of MethodNode.

**PURPOSE:**

I want to generate a MethodNode for each class instance, and each instance keeps references to the generated one. In the first code, what my idea is to create a ClassNode and the target MethodNode directly, during which let the `_node` points to the target MethodNode directly. By this way, there is only 1 visiting of whole ClassNode, i.e., getting MethodNode during the ClassNode creation.

For the 2nd part code, using ClassWriter and visit it. After `cw.visitEnd()`, I have to visit it again to obtain ClassNode, that is `reader.accept(classNode, 0);`. There are twice visiting of the Class.

Comment: Your combination of “thread safe” code and local variables can’t be correct, regardless of what you are trying to achieve. The most obvious thing is that you are assigning `_node` twice rentering the first assignment (and this the entire `MethodNode` creation) obsolete, whereas the second `MethodNode` is connected to an entirely local `ClassNode`. But anyway, it’s not clear why you are dealing with the tree API at all, when all you actually do is calling visitor methods. Your code would be much simpler when just using a `ClassWriter` and its `MethodVisitor`.

Comment: Of course, then you have to call the visit methods again each time you generate a new class, but whether you do it or the `ClassNode` and `MethodNode` do it behind the scenes makes no difference. You are only complicating your design for no benefit.

Comment: Thanks @Holger. Do you mean the 2nd part code when you are saying ``assigning _node twice``? In the 1st part code, the ``_node`` is only assigned by ``(MethodNode) classNode.visitMethod();``, and my problem is at the 1st part code. I add my purpose at the end of my post.

Comment: @Holger, sorry, I have not make the comments clear. The first one is comment out by ``//`` at beginning.  May be better to remove all comments so that no confuse.

Comment: I see. Well, I added the [Java] tag so you get syntax highlighting. That solves the problem as well.